# recursive backtracking to list all subsets with a given sum?

Tags: python, recursion, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to print all possible subarrays that sum up to a given target number.

```
# arr -- the array
# n -- length of the array
# target_sum -- sum we want
# target_arr -- subarray we test for having the right sum
# ite -- iterator

def subset_sum(arr,n,target_sum,target_arr=[],ite=0):
    for i in range(ite,n):
        target_arr.append(arr[i])
        if sum(target_arr)==target_sum:
            print (target_arr, len(target_arr))
            target_arr.pop()
            subset_sum(arr,n,target_sum,target_arr,ite+1)
            return
        subset_sum(arr,n,target_sum,target_arr,i+1)
        target_arr.pop()

subset_sum([1,2,3,4],4,4)
[1, 3] 2
[1, 3] 2
[4] 1
[4] 1
[4] 1
[4] 1.
```

I seem to be able to print all the subarrays, but I don't know why my code has me printing duplicates. I thought the duplicates would be avoided because I pop my subarray at the end (i.e. backtracking).

Where in my code is causing repeats? I have tried but can't figure out why.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: This is in Python.

Answer (score 1):

> Where in my code is causing repeats?

I'm going to rearrange your code a bit: it'll return results instead of printing them; it'll rearrange its arguments so that `target_array` doesn't need to be passed; it'll use an even simpler example input with duplicates:

```
def subset_sum(array, target_sum, start=0, target_array=[]):  # dangerous default value
    solutions = []

    for idx in range(start, len(array)):
        target_array.append(array[idx])

        if sum(target_array) == target_sum:
            solutions.append(list(target_array))
            target_array.pop()
            solutions.extend(subset_sum(array, target_sum, start + 1))
            break

        solutions.extend(subset_sum(array, target_sum, idx + 1))

        target_array.pop()

    return solutions

print(*subset_sum([1, 2, 3], 4))
```

But it still has the same duplication issue:

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 3] [1, 3]
>
```

Now, I'll add a debugging print statement:

```
        target_array.pop()
        print(f"print(*subset_sum({array}, {target_sum}, {start}, {target_array}))")
        solutions.extend(subset_sum(array, target_sum, start + 1))
```

Now when we run it, we get:

```
> python3 test.py
print(*subset_sum([1, 2, 3], 4, 1, [1]))
print(*subset_sum([1, 2, 3], 4, 2, [1]))
[1, 3] [1, 3]
>
```

We can confirm by replacing our original invocation with the two above that both produce the same output.  With a little more `print`-based sleuthing, we can determine that the first is a result of the inner loop recursive call and the second is a result of the outer loop recursive call.  There's no duplication in the call (arguments), but two different calls produce the same result.

You can pull out your hair trying to fix that, or simply switch `solutions` to be a `set` instead of a `list` and let Python filter out the duplicates in your original example call:

```
def subset_sum(array, target_sum, start=0, target_array=[]):  # dangerous default value
    solutions = set()

    for idx in range(start, len(array)):
        target_array.append(array[idx])

        if sum(target_array) == target_sum:
            solutions.add(tuple(target_array))
            target_array.pop()
            solutions |= subset_sum(array, target_sum, start + 1)
            break

        solutions |= subset_sum(array, target_sum, idx + 1)

        target_array.pop()

    return solutions

print(*subset_sum([1, 2, 3, 4], 4))
```

With output:

```
> python3 test.py
(1, 3) (4,)
>
```